# w3cjs validate html file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails project that need to use w3cjs lib.

The lib is in link below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/w3cjs

Anyone can help me to add the lib into project by manual because i can not find out any gem for this lib.

I need validate html file/html string that accords w3c standard. I am using RoR.
Are there any client lib/gem (not use ruby code, just javascript) can do this.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

Check this project out:

https://github.com/sitevalidator/site_validator

After installing you just pass the url to your site.

```
gem install site_validator
site_validator http://example.com
```

Comment: I just need to validate file/string not site, and i am looking for client gem/lib that just use javascript code.